# How do you install fishshell completions and manpages for firefox

Tags: firefox, autocomplete, fish, manpage

I would like to generate autocomplete completions for firefox browser in the fish shell. For example, this [firefox.fish](https://github.com/jwfh/config/blob/master/.local/share/fish/generated_completions/firefox.fish) found on github.

I have tried `fish_update_completions` which updates the available completions but that does not work because there is not manpage for firefox on this machine. How does one install a manpage for firefox?

My env variables are:

```sh
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.2
BuildVersion:   20D64
Firefox:        86.0 (64-bit)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox apparently doesn't provide a man page upstream (via https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1381866#c6 and https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1334025), so you'll have to get one from a distro (e.g. [Ubuntu's](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man1/firefox.1.html)), write your own, or write your own completion script.

Note that apparently all of the available man pages are severely out of date, so generating completions from those will also yield out of date completions.